# How can I get non-matching groups using a Matcher in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a java regex to catch some groups of words from a String using a `Matcher`.

Say i got this string: `"Hello, we are @happy@ to see you today"`.

I would like to get 2 group of matches, one having

```
Hello, we are
to see you today
```

and the other

```
happy
```

So far, I was only able to match the word between the @s using this `Pattern`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@(.+?)@");
```

I've read about negative lookahead and lookaround, played a bit with it but without success.

I assume I should do some sort of negation of the regex so far, but I couldn't come up with anything.

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What about splitting the string using the pattern?

Comment: Splitting is the actual approach I'm using, but I need to keep memory of the text between the @s AND the rest of the text as separate groups, so that I can tell what was between the @s and what not

Comment: You can simply use `string.split("@")` where the first and last element will be the stuff outside the `@` and the middle element will be the stuff between the `@`. It gets complicated though when you only have a single `@` or more than 2

Comment: @Lino yeah that's my problem, I may incur in a string where I got more than one instances of words wrapped by @, such as "@Hello@ kind @stranger@".

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454) to me. Why do you want the text outside? --- My guess would be that you want to replace the `@happy@` text with some replacement text that depends on the word inside the `@...@`, e.g. replace `@happy@` with `glad`, and `@Hello@` with `aloha`, or something like that. For that, you don't need the text outside at all.

Comment: @Andreas I need to apply some different style format to both the text inside and outside.

Comment: @Matteo what would you do for the string `outer1@inner1@inner2@outer2` what belongs now to the inner group and what to the outer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62530428/how-can-i-get-non-matching-groups-using-a-matcher-in-java?noredirect=1#comment110583167_62530428):

> I may incur in a string where I got more than one instances of words wrapped by @, such as "@Hello@ kind @stranger@"

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62530428/how-can-i-get-non-matching-groups-using-a-matcher-in-java?noredirect=1#comment110584149_62530428):

> I need to apply some different style format to both the text inside and outside.

Since you need to apply different stylings, the code need to process each block of text separately, and needs to know if the text is inside or outside a `@..@` section.

Note, in the following code, it will silently skip the last `@`, if there is an odd number of them.

```java
String input = ...
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^@]+)|@([^@]+)@").matcher(input); m.find(); ) {
    if (m.start(1) != -1) {
        String outsideText = m.group(1);
        System.out.println("Outside: \"" + outsideText + "\"");
    } else {
        String insideText = m.group(2);
        System.out.println("Inside: \"" + insideText + "\"");
    }
}
```

*Output for `input = "Hello, we are @happy@ to see you today"`*

```
Outside: "Hello, we are "
Inside: "happy"
Outside: " to see you today"
```

*Output for `input = "@Hello@ kind @stranger@"`*

```
Inside: "Hello"
Outside: " kind "
Inside: "stranger"
```

*Output for `input = "This @text@ has unpaired @ characters"`*

```
Outside: "This "
Inside: "text"
Outside: " has unpaired "
Outside: " characters"
```

Comment: Sidenote: if this method is used often it could be a performace increase to save the `Pattern.compile("([^@]+)|@([^@]+)@")` to a `private static final` variable

Comment: Thank you! This works as I wanted. It would have took ages for me to get to that regex.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could do is splitting in 3 groups, then merging the group 1 and 4 :

```
(^.*)(\@(.+?)\@)(.*)
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/KPqOEm/1/)

**EDIT:** Taking remarks from the comments :

```
(^[^\@]*)(?:\@(.+?)\@)([^\@]*)
```

Thanks to @Lino we don't capture the useless group with @ anymore, and we capture anything except @, instead of any non whitespace character in the 1st and 2nd groups.

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/KPqOEm/2)

Comment: You can make the second group a no-capture-group by using `?:`. E.g. something like this: `(^.*)(?:\@(.+?)\@)(.*)`

Comment: Also maybe replace `.` with `[^\@]` to match anything **but** an `@`

Comment: Thank you. This works for strings where @something@ appears only once, but how to make it work for more than one?

Comment: @Lino Can you take the lead ? I can't manage to do it

Answer (score 1):

Is this solution fine?

```
    Pattern pattern =
            Pattern.compile("([^@]+)|@([^@]*)@");

    Matcher matcher =
            pattern.matcher("Hello, we are @happy@ to see you today");


    List<String> notBetween = new ArrayList<>();  // not surrounded by @
    List<String> between = new ArrayList<>();  // surrounded by @

    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(matcher.group(1))) notBetween.add(matcher.group(1));
        if (Objects.nonNull(matcher.group(2))) between.add(matcher.group(2));
    }

    System.out.println("Printing group 1");
    for (String string :
            notBetween) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    System.out.println("Printing group 2");
    for (String string :
            between) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Comment: *Caveat:* This solution loses track of the original sequence of text fragments.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for the retention of the original sequence.

Comment: OP did ask to support multiple `@...@` blocks either, except in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62530428/5221149?noredirect=1#comment110583167_62530428). --- Anyway, OP [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62530428/5221149?noredirect=1#comment110584149_62530428) *"I need to apply some different style format to both the text inside and outside"*. --- Combined, whose two comments implies that OP needs to build a formatted text string, with the text in original order, but having different text styles, e.g. text outside is green and text inside is red.

Comment: All the comments of OP, you mentioned, stand good. But OP, in his illustrated output, combined all the matches outside `@` together in a list and inside `@` in another list. so I inferred he is not bothered about it and just wants to retrieve the groups. Moreover, he sounded keen on getting the right regex above all.

Comment: I was mainly looking for the right regex at first, but since @Andreas provided a more ready-to-use answer to my question, I accepted his answer. Thank you both, and sorry if I was not completely clear from the beginning